# Corda LinearState: trying to transfer consumed state from one owner to the other

Tags: java, corda

I am trying to transfer a state from one owner to the other back and forth. So always end up having new state created with same values. But intend to pass the state even if it is consumed to another owner. Trying to achieve this with linear state. I have pasted the transfer flow that basically should use the same car state that was issued to transfer across owners. The same consumed car state should be possible to transfer back and forth with the same state being consumed agian and again. Is this possible in Corda. From atheory perspective I am trying to transfer the car back and forth between two or more partys.

**State**

```
  @ConstructorForDeserialization
    public CarState(String carMake, String carModel, int carYear, double carMileAge, String carVIN, Party issuer, Party owner,UniqueIdentifier linearId) {
        this.carMake = carMake;
        this.carModel = carModel;
        this.carYear = carYear;
        this.carMileAge = carMileAge;
        this.carVIN = carVIN;
        this.issuer = issuer;
        this.owner = owner;
        this.linearId = linearId;
    }
```

**Contract**

```
        if(!(inputState.getLinearId().getExternalId().equals(outputState.getLinearId().getExternalId()))){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("UUID of input state and output state must be same");
        }
```

**Flow**

```
@InitiatingFlow
@StartableByRPC
public class CarTransferFlowInitiator extends FlowLogic<String> {

//    private final String carMake;
//    private final String carModel;
//    private final int carYear;
    private final String carVin;
//    private final double carMileage;
    private final Party carOwner;
    private final UniqueIdentifier linearId;
    private int input;



    public CarTransferFlowInitiator(String carVin,Party carOwner,UniqueIdentifier linearId){
        this.carVin = carVin;
        this.carOwner = carOwner;
        this.linearId = linearId;
    }

    private final ProgressTracker.Step RETRIEVING_NOTARY = new ProgressTracker.Step("Retrieving Notary");
    private final ProgressTracker.Step CREATE_TRANSACTION_INPUT= new ProgressTracker.Step("Creating Transaction Input");
    private final ProgressTracker.Step CREATE_TRANSACTION_OUTPUT= new ProgressTracker.Step("Creating Transaction Output");
    private final ProgressTracker.Step  CREATE_TRANSACTION_BUILDER= new ProgressTracker.Step("Creating transaction Builder");
    private final ProgressTracker.Step SIGN_TRANSACTION = new ProgressTracker.Step("Signing Transaction");
    private final ProgressTracker.Step INITIATE_SESSION = new ProgressTracker.Step("Initiating session with counterparty");
    private final ProgressTracker.Step FINALIZE_FLOW = new ProgressTracker.Step("Finalizing the flow");


    private final ProgressTracker progressTracker = new ProgressTracker(
            RETRIEVING_NOTARY,
            CREATE_TRANSACTION_OUTPUT,
            CREATE_TRANSACTION_BUILDER,
            SIGN_TRANSACTION,
            INITIATE_SESSION,
            FINALIZE_FLOW
    );


    @Override
    public ProgressTracker getProgressTracker() {
        return progressTracker;
    }


    public StateAndRef<CarState> checkForCarStates() throws FlowException {


        //QueryCriteria generalCriteria = new QueryCriteria.VaultQueryCriteria(Vault.StateStatus.UNCONSUMED);

        QueryCriteria generalCriteria = new QueryCriteria.VaultQueryCriteria(Vault.StateStatus.ALL);

        List<StateAndRef<CarState>> CarStates = getServiceHub().getVaultService().queryBy(CarState.class, generalCriteria).getStates();

        boolean inputFound = false;
        int t = CarStates.size();
        input = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < t; x++) {
           if (CarStates.get(x).getState().getData().getCarVIN().equals(carVin)) {
           // if (CarStates.get(x).getState().getData().getLinearId().getExternalId().equals(linearId.getExternalId())) {
                input = x;
                inputFound = true;
            }
        }


        if (inputFound) {
            System.out.println("\n Input Found");
//            System.out.println(CarStates.get(input).getState().getData().getCarMake());
//            System.out.println(CarStates.get(input).getState().getData().getCarModel());
//            System.out.println(CarStates.get(input).getState().getData().getCarYear());
//            System.out.println(CarStates.get(input).getState().getData().getCarMileAge());
//            System.out.println(CarStates.get(input).getState().getData().getCarVIN());

        } else {
            System.out.println("\n Input not found");
            throw new FlowException();
        }

        return CarStates.get(input);
    }


    @Suspendable
    public String call() throws FlowException {

        //Retrieve the notary identity from the network map
        progressTracker.setCurrentStep(RETRIEVING_NOTARY);
        Party notary = getServiceHub().getNetworkMapCache().getNotaryIdentities().get(0);

        //Create transaction components both input and output for this application
        progressTracker.setCurrentStep(CREATE_TRANSACTION_OUTPUT);
        StateAndRef<CarState> inputState = null;
        inputState = checkForCarStates();


        //Issuer is Toyota
        //Owner is  AutoSmart

        Party issuer = inputState.getState().getData().getIssuer();
        PublicKey issuerKey = issuer.getOwningKey();

        //Create  transaction components both input and output for this application
        progressTracker.setCurrentStep(CREATE_TRANSACTION_OUTPUT);
        //CarState outputState = new CarState(carMake,carModel,carYear,carMileage,carVin,issuer,carOwner);

        String carMake = inputState.getState().getData().getCarMake();
        String carModel = inputState.getState().getData().getCarModel();
        int carYear = inputState.getState().getData().getCarYear();
        double carMile  = inputState.getState().getData().getCarMileAge();
        String carVIN = inputState.getState().getData().getCarVIN();
        Party carIssuer = inputState.getState().getData().getIssuer();
        UniqueIdentifier carLinearId = inputState.getState().getData().getLinearId();

        System.out.println(carLinearId);
        CarState outputState = new CarState(carMake,carModel,carYear,carMile, carVin,carIssuer,carOwner,carLinearId);

        List<PublicKey> requiresSigners = Arrays.asList(issuerKey,getOurIdentity().getOwningKey(),outputState.getOwner().getOwningKey());
//        requiresSigners.add(outputState.getIssuer().getOwningKey());
//        requiresSigners.add(outputState.getOwner().getOwningKey());

        final Command<CarContract.Transfer> txCommand = new Command<>(
                new CarContract.Transfer(),
                requiresSigners
        );

        final TransactionBuilder txBuilder = new TransactionBuilder(notary)
                .addInputState(inputState)
                .addOutputState(outputState, CID)
                .addCommand(txCommand);

        // Create the transaction builder here and add compenents to it
        progressTracker.setCurrentStep(CREATE_TRANSACTION_BUILDER);
        //TransactionBuilder txB = new TransactionBuilder(notary);
        //   PublicKey issuerKey = getServiceHub().getMyInfo().getLegalIdentitiesAndCerts().get(0).getOwningKey();
        // PublicKey ownerKey = carOwner.getOwningKey();
        //List<PublicKey> requiredSigners = ImmutableList.of(issuerKey,ownerKey);
        //ArrayList<PublicKey> requiredSigners = new ArrayList<PublicKey>();
        //requiredSigners.add(issuerKey);
        //requiredSigners.add(ownerKey);


        // Command cmd = new Command(new CarContract.Register(), getOurIdentity().getOwningKey());
        //txB.addOutputState(outputState, CID)
        //      .addCommand(cmd);

        // Sign the transaction
        progressTracker.setCurrentStep(SIGN_TRANSACTION);
        final SignedTransaction signedTx = getServiceHub().signInitialTransaction(txBuilder);






        // Create session with counterparty
        progressTracker.setCurrentStep(INITIATE_SESSION);
        FlowSession issuePartySession = initiateFlow((issuer));
        FlowSession otherPartySession = initiateFlow(carOwner);

        ArrayList<FlowSession> sessions = new ArrayList<>();
        sessions.add(otherPartySession);
        sessions.add(issuePartySession);

        final SignedTransaction fullySignedTx = subFlow(
                new CollectSignaturesFlow(signedTx, sessions, CollectSignaturesFlow.Companion.tracker()));

//        SignedTransaction fullySignedTx = subFlow(new CollectSignaturesFlow(
//                signedTx, Arrays.asList(otherPartySession), CollectSignaturesFlow.tracker()));


        //Finalizing  the transaction
        progressTracker.setCurrentStep(FINALIZE_FLOW);
        subFlow(new FinalityFlow(fullySignedTx,sessions));

        return "Transfer Completed";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a second constructor for your linear state which accepts as input parameter a `linearId`; you should mark the constructor with the annotation `@ConstructorForDeserialization`.

Otherwise, when your flow suspends (for any reason) and it serializes your linear state, when the flow will attempt to resume and deserialize the state; it will use your current constructor which generates a random linearId, so the flow will end up with a new/different state than yours (because it has a different `linearId`).

But when you create that second constructor and mark it with the annotation, the flow will use it to deserialize and create an identical state.

You can use that constructor as well when you create the output state instead of using the setter like you do now.

Edit (after you added the flow code):

1. You cannot use a consumed state as an input; that's what's known as the double-spend problem. Imagine you had a US Dollar state and you tried to use the same dollar twice to buy things; that cannot happen. The notary will throw and exception if you try to use a consumed state as an input.
2. That's why when you query, you should query for `UNCONSUMED` instead of `ALL`.
3. Your query solution is not correct and not efficient, imagine if you had 100,000 cars; you're going to fetch all 100,000 then loop through them until you find the car with the VIN that you want? First of all you need pagination (Corda will throw an error if your result set returns more than 200 records and you're not using pagination), second of all this will probably drain your Java heap from creating those 100,000 objects and crash your CorDapp.
4. Instead, you should create a custom schema for your car state; then use a custom query criteria to query by the VIN number. Have a look at the IOU example how they created a custom schema for IOU state (see [here](https://github.com/corda/samples-java/tree/master/Basic/cordapp-example/contracts-java/src/main/java/com/example/schema) and [here](https://github.com/corda/samples-java/blob/2c0a4a8f72d624aa99f266b2e09a00082c2a1735/Basic/cordapp-example/contracts-java/src/main/java/com/example/state/IOUState.java#L53-L67)). Then you can use the custom schema in a `VaultCustomQueryCriteria` (read [here](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.5/api-vault-query.html)).

Comment: So, followed the instruction but getting NullPointerException in the Transfer Flow.

Comment: You can update your question with the full code of your flow if possible; then I can have a look.

Comment: [ERROR] 00:03:49-0400 [RxIoScheduler-2] internal.GeneralExceptionHandler. - Exception in thread "RxIoScheduler-2" [errorCode=14ajzzg, moreInformationAt=https://errors.corda.net/OS/4.4/14ajzzg]

Comment: I meant edit your question and add the full code of the flow, not the error.

Comment: I have attached the complete TransferFlowInitiator under Flow

Comment: Also, if possible please refer to me any Java sample code that utilizes LinearState and achieves what I am trying to do.

Comment: I suggest you spend a lot of time inspecting the IOU example (found [here](https://github.com/corda/samples-java/tree/master/Basic/cordapp-example)); it's part of the `java-samples` [repo](https://github.com/corda/samples-java) which I highly recommend that you go through in full.